# Execute Javascript automatically?

Tags: javascript

I have this script that greys out the entire website and brings up a dialogue box when the text 'showPopUp' is clicked. My question is how can i get this script to execute automatically on page load?

Script:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function showPopUp(el) {
        var cvr = document.getElementById("cover")
        var dlg = document.getElementById(el)
        cvr.style.display = "block"
        dlg.style.display = "block"
        if(document.body.style.overflow = "hidden") {
            cvr.style.width = "1024"
            cvr.style.height = "100&#37;"
        }
    }

    function closePopUp(el) {
        var cvr = document.getElementById("cover")
        var dlg = document.getElementById(el)
        cvr.style.display = "none"
        dlg.style.display = "none"
        document.body.style.overflowY = "scroll"
    }
</script>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [how do I automatically execute javascript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2644615/how-do-i-automatically-execute-javascript)

Answer (score 3):

```
window.onload = function() {
  showPopUp('yourObjeID');
};
```

or

```
<body onload="showPopUp('yourObjeID');">
```

or insert script before body ends:

```
...
<script>
    showPopUp('yourObjeID');
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Sorry about that, I did not notice. Edited.

Answer (score 1):

Use `window.onload`. Documentation at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.onload

Answer (score 0):

The better aproach is to use the "document.ready" event, not window.load, because the load event is just triggered after ALL page resources are loaded, while the ready event is triggered after the document is ready (all HTML is loaded and the DOM is ready).

Note that the "document.ready" event is not an event implemented in JavaScript but "emulated" by some JavaScript libraries like jQuery.

Instead of writing an example, I got these two links, take a look:

- [javascript:how to write $(document).ready like event without jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3989095/javascripthow-to-write-document-ready-like-event-without-jquery)
- [window.onload vs $(document).ready()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3698200/window-onload-vs-document-ready)

Comment: Hey David, I don't think JavaScript has a "document.ready" event. Keep in mind this is tagged "JavaScript".

Comment: @jmort253: Yep, I know it (I used double quotes). I'm improving my answer ;)

Comment: Cool! Digging into the jQuery source and pulling out the JS! Awesome!